# Git - forcefully ask for credentials on every push?

Tags: git, authentication

How do I make git ask for credentials (username+password) every time there's a push?

We have a shared host where a logal git repository is taking care of version-controlling a bunch of files. I want to push the repository to a remote location over http, and ask for the username+password every time (since this is a shared host, this ensures we track who was responsible for the last changes).

I have done:

```
git init
git remote add origin http://remote.host/the_git_repo
```

However, when I push, I get an HTTP 401 error and **no username/password prompt**:

> [user@thehost ~]# git push -u origin master error: The requested URL
>   returned error: 401 Unauthorized while accessing
>   http://remote.host/the_git_repo/info/refs
>
> fatal: HTTP request failed

The `.git/config` file contents:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        askpass = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = http://remote.host/the_git_repo
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Notes:

- SSH login is not available for this remote repo
- I have read the documentation about the `SSH_ASKPASS` and `GIT_ASKPASS` environment variables, but it is not clear how to use them (`export GIT_ASKPASS=1` does nothing)
- This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25735957/810448), the difference is that the repository was just created and noone has input any credentials yet

Comment: Did you try `git remote add origin http://user@remote.host/the_git_repo`?

Comment: That won't do it. The pushes have to be authenticated with the user that did the changes (the local repository is in a shared location). That way, either everyone pushes with the same user, or they'll have to change `.git/config` every time.

Comment: I guess I missed that this was a shared host. So you're tracking who did what changes not by who committed them, but by who pushed them?