# How to force Git Bash to ask for credentials on each push

Tags: git, gitlab, git-bash

Is there a configuration in Git Bash or even on the server side on GitLab, to force the user to enter the connection credentials to the remote repository, every time it does a push?

Comment: Use SSH key with password and no agent?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs what do you mean by no agent?

Comment: Read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90869/2056).

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735957/how-do-i-make-git-ask-for-a-username-and-password-every-time-i-push

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make git ask for a username and password every time I push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735957/how-do-i-make-git-ask-for-a-username-and-password-every-time-i-push)